# Is my fast broken or not?

Tags: quran, hadith, islamic-philosophy

I am fasting and Unfortunately i tasted my tears while am crying so i do not know about this situation is my fast broken or not please help me through hadith

Comment: Did you swallow the tears?

Comment: Not swallow but i tasted them and then i spit out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, tears contain water mixed with enzymes so swallowing such will break your fast. If you swallow anything that can break your fast whether by accident and you havent forgotten that you are fasting then your fast is broken, void. If you forgot that you were fasting and you did swallow anything that break your fast then your fast is not broken, void.

Answer (score 1):

In a few words;

If you swallowed them intentionally, the fast is rendered broken.
If you swallowed them accidentally, the fast is rendered broken and should be made up.
If you swallowed them forgetfully, then the fast still valid and you can continue.

Reference for crying: 
http://www.islamandquran.org/fatwas/swallowing-tears-accidentally-while-crying.html

Reference for establishing which category you fall under and the difference: https://www.seekersguidance.org/answers/hanafi-fiqh/accidental-forgetful-breaking-of-the-fast-what-is-the-difference/

And Allah knows best.